# Не загружается NPAPI плагин для браузера

Tags: c, c++

Имеется написанный на С++ плагин для браузера. При загрузке страницы все отображается корректно, нет сообщений об ошибках, но вызов функции плагина не происходит. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас не прописаны ресурсы. Важно, чтобы в ресурсах было выставлено свойство MIMEType. Например:

```
MIMEType application/my-extension-type
```